# Form Validation Works But Still Submits When User Input The Wrong Answer

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I wrote a Javascript to validate my forms before submission.
The function of the Javascript is to prevent my form from submitting itself when a user provides a phone number that matches with the result in my Javascript but rather shows an error message that says "Phone number already used!"

My problem is that the validation works fine: Users get an alert that the phone number they provided has been used but my form still submits itself after showing the error message.

What am I not doing rightly?

Below is my code.

```js
function check(form) /*function to check used phone number*/ {
    /*the following code checkes whether the entered phone number is matching*/

  if (form.phonenum.value == "0807575566464" 
|| form.phonenum.value == "09057487463") 
{
    alert("Phone number used! provide a new one! \n") /*displays error message*/
} else if (form.phonenum.value.length<11 || form.phonenum.value.length>11) { alert("Phone number should be 11 digits! \nAnd it should begin with; 080, 081, 070, 090, or 091.");
} 
else {
    return false;
  }

 
}
```

```html
<form action='' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formName">
  <input type="text" id="phonenum" name="myinput">
  <button href='/' type='submit' onclick="check(this.form)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

Comment: @tbs yes but can you do me a favor by correcting my javascript. I am an amateur. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add e.preventDefault() in order for it to stop reloading the page when you hit submit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a function to the onsubmit event and stop the event if the validaiton fails.

HTML:

```
<form action='' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formName" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm(event) {
  if(validation fails...) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ....
  }
}
```

Documentation and examples for the preventDefault function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Instead of using event.preventDefault() you could also just return false:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65538474/9441244

In your case your JavaScript should look like this

HTML:

```
<form action='/test/' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formName" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
  <input type="text" id="phonenum" name="myinput">
  <button href='/' type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm(event) {
    if (this.phonenum.value == "0807575566464" || this.phonenum.value == "09057487463") {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Phone number used! provide a new one! \n");
    } else if (this.phonenum.value.length != 11) { 
        this.preventDefault();
        alert("Phone number should be 11 digits! \nAnd it should begin with; 080, 081, 070, 090, or 091.");
    }
}
```